# Handling $resource object parameter

Tags: angularjs

Having the following $resource service:

```
myService.factory('Phones', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/Phones', { phoneName: '@phoneName' }, {
        submit: { method: 'POST', },
    });
});
```

Calling submit on the returned $resource object will post the phoneName as a parameter e.g. 
**`/api/Phones?phoneName=Nokia`**.
However calling the same resource object with the GET method will also use the phoneName parameter as undefined e.g. 
**`/api/Phones?phoneName=undefined`**.

Is it possible to prevent the phoneName to appear for the GET method using the same $resource object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your service to this:

```
myService.factory('Phones', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/Phones', {}, {
        submit: { 
          method: 'POST'
        }
    });
});
```

That way you only define the paramater 'phoneName' on the 'submit' action and not all actions.

**Edit:** You don't need to define `phoneName` as a param in the $resource action.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now if I call the service like this:
`Phones.submit({ phoneName: 'Nokia' });`
it will no longer replace the @phoneName attribute instead it outputs:
/api/Phones?phoneName=@phoneName

Any idea how to solve this?